# Calling Rest api of two different web application site present in same SharePoint farm?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api

When trying to access, i am getting No "**Access-Control-Allow-Origin**" header is present. Why such error is getting occurred even if present in same farm.
Even GET operation of list is getting failed !

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable cross site scripting for your site.

You could check the powershell script shared by Ingo Karstein.

https://blog.kenaro.com/2014/03/18/cross-site-scripting-with-sharepoint-2013-rest-calls/